# In Kotlin/JS(Kotlin Multiplatform), how can I get the API Key listed in local.properties?

Tags: gradle, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-js

In Kotlin/JS, how can I get the API Key written in local.properties?
There is a lot of information on how to get the API Key described in local.properties in Android, but I don't know how to get it in Kotlin/Js (Kotlin Multiplatform). Can someone please tell me how to do this? I am not a native English speaker, so sorry if my English is strange.

In Kotlin/JS, I want to get the API Key listed in local.properties.

Comment: You can use [`BuildKofig`](https://github.com/yshrsmz/BuildKonfig), it'll generate kotlin class for you, and to pass the needed data from Gradle you can use regular techniques you've already found

Comment: @PhilDukhov It worked well. Can I ask you to reanswer your comment if possible so I can accept it?